# drag from one <table> to another using javascript without any plugins

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two tables: Passengers and Flights.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>
Passenger Name
</th>
<th>
Passenger Flight
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Passenger 1
</td>
<td>
FR5412
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
.....
<tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<th>
Flight Number
</th>
<th>
Current capacity
</th>
<th>
Max capacity
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
FR45321
</td>
<td>
23
</td>
<td>
198
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
.....
<tr>
</table>
```

I need to drag passenger from table Passengers to Flight and at this moment change Flight Number of passenger in Passengers to FlightNumber in Flights on which I drop it and increase Capacity in Flight, to which we drag Passenger.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```js
let item = null;
        function startDragging(e) {
            item = e.target;
            e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "");
        }
        function dragOverHandler(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        function dropHandler(e) {
            if(parseInt(e.target.parentElement.children[1].outerText) < parseInt(e.target.parentElement.children[2].outerText)) {
                const customer = item.querySelector("td:last-child");
                if(customer.outerText != e.target.parentElement.children[0].outerText) {
                    customer.textContent = e.target.parentElement.children[0].outerText;
                    e.target.parentElement.children[1].textContent = parseInt(e.target.parentElement.children[1].outerText) + 1;
                }
            } else {
                window.alert("This flight is full!");
            }
        }
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Passenger Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Passenger Flight
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr draggable="true" id="c1" ondragstart="startDragging(event)">
            <td>
                Passenger 1
            </td>
            <td>
                FR5412
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr draggable="true" id="c2" ondragstart="startDragging(event)">
            <td>
                Passenger 2
            </td>
            <td>
                FR5412
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr draggable="true" id="c3" ondragstart="startDragging(event)">
            <td>
                Passenger 3
            </td>
            <td>
                FR5412
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr draggable="true" id="c4" ondragstart="startDragging(event)">
            <td>
                Passenger 4
            </td>
            <td>
                FR5412
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Flight Number
            </th>
            <th>
                Current capacity
            </th>
            <th>
                Max capacity
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event)">
            <td>
                FR45321
            </td>
            <td>
                23
            </td>
            <td>
                198
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event)">
            <td>
                FR45322
            </td>
            <td>
                23
            </td>
            <td>
                198
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event)">
            <td>
                FR45323
            </td>
            <td>
                23
            </td>
            <td>
                198
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event)">
            <td>
                FR45324
            </td>
            <td>
                203
            </td>
            <td>
                198
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```